# Draw multiple scenes using form paint?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, paint

Hello I would like to draw multiple scenes on Form using Paint like this, but with timer tick I would like it to redraw to another scene( here rectangles).

Is it possible to have multiple `Form_Paint` events?

```
private void choose()
{
     switch (sceneNumber)
        {
            case 1:

                this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(ScreenSaverForm_Paint);
                sceneNumber=++;

                break;
            case 2:


               this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(ScreenSaverForm_Paint2);

                sceneNumber=++;
                break;
            default:


                this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(ScreenSaverForm_Paint3);

                sceneNumber=1;
                break;
        }

    }

private void ScreenSaverForm_Paint1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Pen pero = new Pen(Brushes.White);

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawRectangle(pero, 0, 0, 200, 200);
    }

    private void ScreenSaverForm_Paint2(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen pero = new Pen(Brushes.Blue);

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, new Rectangle(200, 200, 400, 400));

    }
```

I also tried this with picturebox, but that wasn`t working.
Could somebody explain to me how to draw on Pain or picturebox multiple "scenes" using

```
private void moveTimer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        choose();       

    }
```

where choose will draw next scene depending on global variable sceneNumber?. I`m not really skilled in .NET programming so got messed up with handlers, delegates etc… I just need to redraw some code encapsulated in different functions. Thank you.

Could be somehting like this done with Form_Paint ? This is something

Comment: Don't keep adding paint handlers like that.  You only need to add it once.  Move your switch block inside the paint event.  Instead of calling `choose();`, you call `this.invalidate();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling multiple paint event handlers, just override the OnPaint method of the form, and then call a paint routine based on the scene number:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

  private int sceneNumber;

  public Form1() {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.ResizeRedraw = true;
  }

  private void moveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sceneNumber > 1) {
      sceneNumber = 1;
    } else {
      sceneNumber++;
    }
    this.Invalidate();
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    switch (sceneNumber) {
      case 1:
        DrawSceneOne(e.Graphics);
        break;
      case 2:
        DrawSceneTwo(e.Graphics);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
  }

  private void DrawSceneOne(Graphics g) {
    g.Clear(Color.Wheat);
    // more stuff...
  }

  private void DrawSceneTwo(Graphics g) {
    g.Clear(Color.Silver);
    // more stuff...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I did this effect without Form_Paint (I know that it was the whole point of question to use Form_Paint :D ):

```
public int sceneNumber=1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void choose()
    {

        switch (sceneNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                resetPict();
                drawOne();
                sceneNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                resetPict();
                drawTwo();
                sceneNumber = 1;
                break;

        }

    }

    private void resetPict()
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor= Color.Black;
    }
    private void drawOne()
    {
        Graphics gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();          
        gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 30, 30, 150, 100);

    }
    private void drawTwo()
    {
        Graphics gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();            
        gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 30, 30, 150, 100);
    } 



    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        choose();
    }
}
```

But your method works just fine (and is using Paint) ! Thank you again.

Comment: Avoid CreateGraphics.  Minimizing your form will erase what was painted, for example.  Always use the graphics object from the Paint event.